# Webpy sessions: AttributeError: 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'username'

Tags: python, web.py

I am making a webapp in python using web.py, I have set up the tables and can login the user and everything, but the initializer for sessions doesn't seem to work.

I have the following in my code:

```
store = web.session.DBStore(db, 'sessions')
session = web.session.Session(app, store, initializer={'logged_in': 0, 'username': ''})

render = web.template.render('templates/', base='base', globals={'session': session, 'username': session.username})
```

But this throws the error: 
**AttributeError: 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'username'**

What can be done? I basically just followed the example here:
http://webpy.org/cookbook/sessions

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, so i used the _initializer property to get session data.

Here's an example:

```
store = web.session.DBStore(db, 'sessions')
session = web.session.Session(app, store, initializer={'logged_in': 0, 'username': ''})

session_data = session._initializer
render = web.template.render('templates/', base='base', globals={'session': session_data, 'username': session_data['username']})
```

You can then access all the data you declared in the initializer from session. If anyone has a better way, please let me know.

PS: I know its late, but better late then never...

Comment: This is a good solution. Getting the session var like this : session_data['logged_in'] - thanks Antonis.

Answer (score 2):

Session is only loaded when request is processed, you cannot get its attributes during setup.

Comment: So I figured out, but it's working now, just don't ask me how lol, cause I have no idea.
Also I had to overwrite the default web.py Session class to make the sessions global for the entire domain instead of each unique url having their own session cookie, that really made no sense to me.

Comment: You don't have to subclass Session for this purpose, just set session parameters: `web.config.session_parameters.update(cookie_name="tasty_cookie", cookie_domain="mydomain.com")`

Comment: The domain is one thing, the path is another, and it was the path that was set to e.g. `//` for **index**, `/login/` for **login** and so forth, thus making the session cookie really not useable at all. I just set the path statically to `"/"` and it suddenly worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get a session variable before it's set.

I've noticed that `session.username` works in some circumstances. But under WSGI it fails.

This works fine and is in the webpy docs :

`session.get('username', False)`

Not :

`session.username`

If you want to use the presets in the initializer, use the method in @Antonis-kalou 's answer.

```
session_data = session._initializer
session.get('username', session_data['username'])
```

Comment: @Antonis-kalou see more info above. 3 years later - but I had the issue just now so I guess it's still relevant.