# 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'session_id'

Tags: python, pycharm, web.py

Anyone please help me to fix this issue. I have already followed [instruciton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025011/webpy-sessions-attributeerror-threadeddict-object-has-no-attribute-username) but still I am not able to fix this issue. I am able to make login but when I click on logout button I only manage to get this error **'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'session_id'**

**Controller.py**

```
session= web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), initializer={'username': None})
session_data = session._initializer

render = web.template.render('view/templete', base='mainlayout', globals={'session' : session_data,'username':session_data['username']})

class Logout:
    def GET(self):
        session['user']= None
        session_data['user'] = None

        session.kill()
        return 'sucess'
```

**javascrip**

```
$(document).on('click','#logout-link',function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/logout',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(res){
                if (res =='sucess'){
                    document.location.href ='/login',true;
                }else{

                    alert('somthing went wrong');
                }

            }


        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug. The way to fix this is to add `web.config.debug = False` just under your imports in your Controller.py class. Rerun your application and it should sort out that error.